# Nodejs com erro de sintaxe

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, mint

Ola, eu uso o linux Mint 20.3.
Instalei o nodejs  e o npm, funcionam normalmente, mas quando eu tento executar um arquivo com node, ele da esse erro ai.
Eu instalei o node em um pc velho que tambem tem mint, e roda normal, Como pode? Alguem sabe oq é?ja aconteceu contigo?
Veja que ele guarda variaveis, executa funções  normalmente, mas nao executa arquivos, nesse caso o index.js(que tem dentro un console.log).
É como se eu tivesse digitado o index errado, mas é assim mesmo, deveria funcionar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para executar o arquivo pela linha de comando dá pra executar no console

```
node caminho/para/arquivo.js
```

Também tem como carregar o arquivo de script dentro do comando `node` se digitar ´.load caminho/para/arquivo.js´

Comment: kkkkkkk nossa perdi muuuito tempo com isso, eu sou muito burro.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo